# Strange printf() result

Tags: c++

In structure *drzewo.root->value* I have '5';

I print it like this, and next I call function findNodeWithValue():

```
printf("%d \n", drzewo.root->value);
return findNodeWithValue(drzewo.root, value);
```

This function is defined like this:

```
Node* findNodeWithValue(Node * wierzcholek, int value) {
    printf("%d \n", wierzcholek->value);
}
```

The result of this program is:

> 5
>
> 4200289

Why?

Here is the whole program: http://pastebin.com/n2iS7bWt

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal _compilable_ example?

Comment: Can you please post the Node struct/class definition?

Comment: Perhaps `value` isn't initialized.

Comment: Don't just post random snippets. Present a [testcase](http://sscce.org), as already requested. You should have done this during your own debugging and, in the process, you'd almost certainly have found the problem. So this is a crucial skill.

Comment: This is unanswerable without an SSCCE (as Lightness points out). But one thing: `findNodeWithValue()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: You should find a bug where you initialize `drzewo` (I assume `drzewo.root = some_value` is operating on a undefined `drzewo`)

Comment: Please consider that '5' (character literal), "5" (string literal) and 5 (integer literal) are completely different concepts in C++.

Comment: I update my post. There is a link to the full code.

Comment: Create a new question. Paste the `insert()` function into the question and ask why it is wrong. PS. It is this line `wierzcholek->left = &node;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that `drzewo.root` is uninitialized and points somewhere on your stack, where the data pushed by the next function call modifies the value pointed to.

**EDIT**

And now that we have the whole source code, we see that this is indeed happening, more or less: In `insert()`, instead of *allocating* a new node, you just *declare* it on the stack. As soon as you leave the scope of the `insert()`, referring to that node's memory is no longer legit.

Luckily, this is fixed easy enough, just allocate the new node properly:

```
drzewo.root = new Node;
drzewo.root->value = value;
```

and if you ever delete your structures, you'll have to remember to delete the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct Node NODE;

struct Node {
    int value;
    NODE * left = NULL;
    NODE * right = NULL;
    NODE * parent = NULL;
    bool parentLeft;
};

struct Tree {
    int levels;
    int n;
    NODE * root = NULL;
};

Tree drzewo;
```

Answer (score 0):

My theory is that your are trying to refer to a local variable outside the scope of `findNodeWithValue()`. When the first function returned program flow changes to `findNodeWithValue(Node * wierzcholek, int value)`. The stack was destroyed and all local variable was also destroyed along with the stack. Thus a pointer to your node will point to a random location which has random value stored in it.